# Enforce that every object in an array of objects has the same shape

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using TypeScript 3.2.2, and I have a React component which accepts an array of objects. The objects are generic, with a few exceptions: they must not be nested, and must all be the same shape. For example:

```
const entries = [
    {title: "foo", description: "bar", message: "hello"},
    {title: "something", description: "a thing", message: "thing"},
    {title: "hello", description: "greeting", message: "greetings!!"}
]
```

Beyond that, I don't care about the contents of the objects. They can have as many properties as they want, the properties can have any name and their values can be any type. But the component will break if, say, one of the objects is missing an entry or has an extra one, or if it contains another object.

Is there a way to express this requirement in the TypeScript type system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
interface MyObject {
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean | undefined | null
}
```

Basically allowing primitive values with any key, so long as that key is of type string. This ensures there are no nested objects or arrays (though you could include Array as a type)

You could also explicitly define properties you might expect as optional to benefit from intellisense and get some extra type safety:

```
interface MyObject {
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean | undefined | null;
  title?: string;
  description?: string;
  message?: string;
}
```

Now that you have your object expressed as an interface, declaring any value as an array of this type can be done in two ways, either:

```
Array<MyObject>
```

or

```
MyObject[]
```

I prefer the latter, some prefer the former. It's just a matter of taste as they both express the idea that a given value is an array containing only members of the designated type.